# How can I fix the last column in a malformatted csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very large (~80gb) csv file that is formatted with spaces as delimiters, however the final column has spaces and so is causing me a huge headache trying to read it in with pandas.

Here's a small segment of the csv i am dealing with:

```
7.942891 7.3e-004 14.64 14.28 14 8 1.2e+001 0.00 6.2e-005 1.2e+000 1.0e-050 4.6e+005 0.54 -1.00 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -0.13 -0.18 -0.08 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7)
7.943618 7.3e-004 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.11 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
7.943619 1.0e-006 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.11 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
17.199911 9.3e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.11 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
26.363639 9.2e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.11 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
35.435729 9.1e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.11 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
44.417096 9.0e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
53.308649 8.9e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
62.111285 8.8e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
70.825893 8.7e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
79.453355 8.6e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
87.994540 8.5e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
96.450313 8.5e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
104.821527 8.4e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
113.109027 8.3e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
121.313652 8.2e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
129.436229 8.1e+000 14.64 12.31 14 14 1.3e+001 0.10 6.2e-005 5.2e-005 1.0e-050 1.0e-050 0.54 0.50 0 0 0.0e+000 0.0e+000 -2.28 -0.72 -1.59 48.79 28.89 1.9e+003 0.69 -5200 12709 MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2
```

The last column should be
the entries:

`MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7)`

`MT1(2-1) SN1 CE2(14-4;14-7) SN2`

etc

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I can read through the file and replace the first 27 spaces in each row with a comma, however I have a lot of very large files, is there a way I can do this faster?

```
with open(dat_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace(' ', ',', 27)
        print(line)
```

Comment: You seem to have clearly identified the last column as a human being.  How did you make that identification?  How do you translate that logic into Python code?  This is the basic concept of problem analysis.

Comment: So far, you've made the first step of analysis, quite accurately: the file is *not* properly formatted as a CSV file.  Therefore, a built-in `csv` function is not likely to produce the desired result.  You either begin with a data-cleaning program, or take what you get as a CSV and combine the resulting fields after the input.  Either way, you haven't explained where you're stuck, nor posted any attempt.  Therefore, this is not yet a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own solution looks quite efficient, but I'd write the output to a file rather than trying to capture the output. Also, for a loop that is going to be executed about one billion times, it's good to have the contents of the loop as compact as possible:

```
with open(dat_file, 'r') as fin, open(f'fixed_{dat_file}', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace(' ', ',', 27))
```

Given that you expect to load 80 GB of data in a single pandas DataFrame, you are likely running this on a system that has many CPU cores. You could split up the work between the CPUs; each CPU starts reading the file from a different point. You can create an empty file of the correct size like this:

```
import os
fsize = os.stat(dat_file).st_size
# create empty (holy) output file
with open(f'fixed_{dat_file}', 'w') as fout:
    fout.seek(fsize-1)
    fout.write(' ')
```

(In Linux, this will create a 'holy' file, which doesn't take disk space until you actually write data to it.) You'll have to handle the beginnings and ends of the blocks so that you don't end up with partial lines.

You can then use [the `multiprocessing` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to manage the processes.

But if you have a lot of similar huge files, it's probably more practical to assign a single file to each CPU.